# Windows 8.1 boot entry gone

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, boot

Previously I had windows 8.1 and windows 7 installed on my machine. Windows 7 was installed later. So I was using windows 7 boot option to select os. I didn't need windows 7 any more so I formatted the local disk where windows 7 was installed from windows 8.1. Nothing wrong happened. But windows 7 boot manager was still there. Then, I tried to use Easybcd software to delete windows 7 from boot manager.Then I restarted but saw only windows 7 on os selection screen ( but I don't have windows 7 now).

**As there is no windows 8.1 option on os selection screen I can't access windows 8.1.**

I have linux live cd so I can access the hard disk. How can solve this problem?

Comment: you use easybcd to add back the entry, you can use your backups, to do this.

Comment: @Ramhound -How?Can you provide any link that can help?

Comment: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-bcdedit.htm. Follow this link. Pop in your live CD and see if you can access this file and update the boot entry

Comment: You can also just use the WinRE and use the command to repair your bootloader that might be easier if you didn't keep backups of your boot.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert your Windows 8 disc and boot it. It will offer you an option to repair your existing installation, and will fix this problem.